# How to append custom td to table generated from two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. I am trying to work out why I am not able to append all `<td>` in one row? What I want to do is appending a custom `<td>` at begging of each rows in a way to look like:

```
<tr>
    <td>Defult TD</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>140</td>
<tr>            

<tr>
    <td>Defult TD</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>145</td>
<tr>
```

but what I am getting is

```
<tr>
    <td>Defult TD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>140</td>
<tr>            
<tr>
    <td>Defult TD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>145</td>
<tr>
```

```js
var sizes= [
   [52, 16, 140],
   [54, 16, 145]
];
var table = $('#size-rows');
var row, cell;
for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
   row = $('<tr />');
   table.append(row);
   cell = $('<td>Default TD</td>')
   for (var j = 0; j < sizes[i].length; j++) {
      cell.append('<td>' + sizes[i][j] + '</td>');
      row.append(cell);
   }
}
```

```css
td{
border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
 <table>
  <tbody id="size-rows"> </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to the `<td>`, instead, append the `cell` and the next `<td>`'s to the `row`:

```js
var sizes = [
  [52, 16, 140],
  [54, 16, 145]
];
var table = $('#size-rows');
var row, cell;
for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
  row = $('<tr />');
  table.append(row);
  cell = $('<td>Default TD</td>');
  row.append(cell);
  for (var j = 0; j < sizes[i].length; j++) {
    row.append('<td>' + sizes[i][j] + '</td>');
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody id="size-rows"> </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution using the map function.

```js
var sizes= [
   [52, 16, 140],
   [54, 16, 145]
];

$('#size-rows').append(
  sizes.map(
    x => `<tr>
            <td>Default TD</td>${x.map(y => `<td>${y}</td>`)}
          </tr>`
          )
 );
```

```css
td{
border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
 <table>
  <tbody id="size-rows"> </tbody>
 </table>
```